# Loss for image rotation?

Tags: keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am solving a problem "Having an image of an object, rotate it, bottom-down, top-up".
I have divided a circle to 360/5 parts, made them one-hot variables and it works... just with a suboptimal accuracy.
What I am looking for is a custom loss function (but I have problems, as I am new to Keras).

What I have so far is

```
def custom_loss(y_actual, y_pred):
  loss = tf.math.minimum(tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.math.argmax(y_actual) 
    - tf.math.argmax(y_pred)))),
  72*72 - tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.math.argmax(y_actual) 
    - tf.math.argmax(y_pred)))))
  return loss
```

The idea is that a traditional one-hot considers elements as independent, while in my case, if the ground truth is 45 degrees, the answer "40 degrees" is less wrong then the answer "90 degrees".

Also, if we have borderline answers, like 5 degrees and 355 degrees, they are actually close, we just need to measure distance "the other way".

Anyway, any ideas what is wrong with the loss quoted above - it doesn't work at all?

Comment: `argmax` is not differentiable function, loss function must be differentiable.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell, how to figure if it is differentiable or not?